# PostgreSQL Get by name and not array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a column named systemproperties and the data in it is in this format:

```json
[
  {"name": "system.totalphysicalmemory", "value": "4.00GB"},
  {"name": "system.enablenetflow", "value": "false"}
]
```

This is the way how I get the value for totalphysicalmemory:

```
SELECT
jsonb_array_element(system_properties::jsonb, 0) ->> 'value'  as total_physical_memory
FROM mytable
```

This one works but not all of the records have the same index for totalphysicalmemory. I am trying to find a way to get the value by name instead.

I tried to crashcourse on json/postgresql but I am not getting any good results. Thank you!

This is the way how I get the value for totalphysicalmemory:

```
SELECT
jsonb_array_element(system_properties::jsonb, 0) ->> 'value'  as total_physical_memory
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON path query

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(systemproperties, '$[*] ?(@.name == "system.totalphysicalmemory").value)')
from mytable;
```